# Password protecting a private NTFS folder

Tags: 11.10, password, ntfs

Here's the story. I recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows using the Wubi installer. The issue is that I have a private folder on my Windows NTFS partition. It is configured so that no listing permissions are given to any other user but mine. The folder is password protected in Windows with FolderGuard. The deal is that this folder is perfectly acessible using my ubuntu installation which makes me concerned. So the question is:

> Is there any way to password protect a folder inside a NTFS partition
>   in Ubuntu?

Ubuntu Virtual disks are on the same partition where the private folder is located.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use encryption. Password protecting a folder, as you have discovered, it useless. Take a look at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) - a cross-platform encryption tool.

Comment: TrueCrypt is a good option, but it would require that all files get moved to a virtal partition or drive. In this situation it wouldn't do it as the folder takes most of my hard drive and there is no way to create a TrueCrypt file or partition. Would encrypting the files from Windows properties make them inaccessible in Ubuntu?

Comment: Probably not, unless MS started to use cross-platform encryption tools.